# strong entity despite having total relationship to an entity.?

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework

how can a entity be a strong entity despite having a total relationship to another entity with 1:1 cardinality . for example , say, Manager entity has a 1:1 total relationship with Department( lets call the relationship as 'managed by'). So, isn't if a department is removed corresponding manager should also be removed.? But the book i refereed to has stated otherwise, it says the Manager entity isn't weak even it has total relationship with Department entity. What am I missing here.? I'm confused.

@oscar :but......? that means there could be times where a manager don't manage a department, so then how can we call it a total relationship.?

Comment: A manager can manage more than one department, for example. If a department disappear, the manager still have others to manage.

Comment: i don't know how to add reps :(

Comment: but......? that means there could be times where a manager don't manage a department so then how can we call it a total relationship.?